# ¿Por que me marca syntax error en INSERT INTO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```php
$SQL = "INSERT INTO datos ( Nombre, Apellido paterno, 
        Apellido materno, No. de control, Grado, Grupo, 
        Turno, Especialidad, Materia, Semestre, Docente, Telefono del alumno) 
        VALUES ( '$variableNombre',  '$variableApp', '$variableAppp', '$variableNode', 
'$variableGrado', '$variableGrupo', '$variableTurno', '$variableEsp', 
'$variableMate', '$variableSem', '$variableDoc', '$variableTel')";
```

[image: Ese es el error que este me marca]

Comment: Tienes espacios de las columnas, empezando por `Apellido paterno` ... si quieres que los tome en cuenta, encierralos de este modo ` `Apellido paterno` ` con esas comillas

Comment: ¿Los nombres de columnas tienen espacios? Evita poner espacios, tildes, ñ 
 en nombres de BD o tablas. Algo opcional: procura en la medida de lo posible que los nombres sean en inglés. Tu problema se resuelve con [tildes invertidas](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+backtick).

Answer (score 0):

Veo que en los `values` envías `('', '', '', etc`.

Debes tener en cuenta si tus columnas son todas de tipo *varchar*, de lo contrario debes enviar data de acuerdo al tipo de dato de la columna y en su defecto validar si puede ser `null` la data que envíes. Si es tu primer formulario prueba con una o dos columnas inicialmente con diferentes tipos de datos.

Mejorando tu *query*

```
"INSERT INTO datos ( Nombre, [Apellido paterno], [Apellido materno], 
[No. de control], Grado, Grupo, Turno, Especialidad, Materia, 
Semestre, Docente, [Telefono del alumno]) 
VALUES ('$variableNombre', '$variableApp', '$variableAppp', 
'$variableNode', '$variableGrado', '$variableGrupo', '$variableTurno', 
'$variableEsp', '$variableMate', '$variableSem', '$variableDoc', '$variableTel')"
```

Puedes intentar probar este sql directamente desde **phpmyadmin** que veo lo tienes instalado, realiza una inserción directamente desde la DB.

Comment: Si, todos son de tipo varchar

Comment: @Gabriel Para mejorar las convenciones de tu DB recomiendo que leas este articulo https://styde.net/convenciones-de-nombres-de-bases-de-datos/

Comment: @Gabriel esto ayudara a minimizar errores al insertar o consultar la información de tu base de datos.

Comment: Ya pude solucionar ese problema pero ahora me acaba de parecer otro nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate bien en el error que te está lanzando, te está diciendo que está teniendo un problema de sintaxis causado justo antes de `paterno`, ya que la sintaxis de MySQL requiere que los nombres no contengan espacios, sino que estén separados preferentemente por `_`.

Tras está modificación el código quedaría así:

```
"INSERT INTO datos (nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno, 
num_control, grado, grupo, turno, especialidad, 
materia, semestre, docente, telefono_alumno) 
VALUES (...)"
```

Una buena práctica a la hora de crear campos en bases de datos es que siempre estén en minúsculas, sin acentos, separados por `_` en caso de que sea más de una palabra, y suprimir las preposiciones.

En cuanto a los valores que le estás pasando ¿estás intentando pasarle variables de PHP? En ese caso la sintaxis es:

```
VALUES("'.$variable.'", "'.$variable.'")
```

Con todo esto, te debería funcionar la consulta, espero haber sido de ayuda ;)

Cheers!